# MongoDB with Editor.js expandable data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, nosql

I am currently designing a blog-type application with a MongoDB backend. The blog application will use `editor.js` to allow the creation and editing of 'blogs'.

https://editorjs.io/

`Editor.js` is very friendly, and returns data like this:

```
{
"time" : 1610826755415,
"blocks" : [
    {
        "type" : "header",
        "data" : {
            "text" : "Editor.js",
            "level" : 2
        }
    },
    {
        "type" : "paragraph",
        "data" : {
            "text" : "Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this page you can see it in action — try to edit this text."
        }
    },
    {
        "type" : "header",
        "data" : {
            "text" : "Key features",
            "level" : 3
        }
    }
}
```

My concern is that even though this is very MongoDB friendly, depending on the size of the blog, it is possible that the document will lean towards the 16MB document limit (which we should get close to). Is there a sensible way to split this up without facing the limits of Mongo? Perhaps taking the different `types` and dividing it up that way?

Thank you.

Comment: If you believe your going to max out your mongodb file size, then you can either multer the file or separate the data into multiple collections and query lookup each file. If you do the second one you will have to aggregate the data and combine it before you respond back to the client. If you didn't want to separate your data into different collections or multer it, you could id separate documents similarly and query them seperately. If your data is relational, then keeping the schema structure nested is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can split out content that can be big by referring to the _id the data is in, e.g.:

If you decide that a paragraph can exceed

```
{
"time" : 1610826755415,
"docId": ObjectId("00000001"),
"blocks" : [       
        {
            "type" : "paragraph",docuId"
            "summary": "Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this page you...",
            "dataId" : ObjectId("123456789")
            }
        },
        {/*other blocks... */}
   ]
}
```

Then have a collection per type where you do your lazy loading. A MongoD collection named paragraph would have records like this:

```
    "ObjectId(123456789)" : {
        "docId": ObjectId("00000001"),
        "text" : "Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this page you can see it in action — try to edit this text."
    }
```

This has the additional benefit of faster db loading/data transfers if you don't need the entire Object : your queries from the browser may include an option "lazy":"true" which will only load the summary of paragraphs and delay   the big content to a later phasis. The docId would allow you to load all dependencies of a document at once